# Make three headings in line. One to be on the left, second on center and third on the right?

Tags: html, css

In a  i have three headings, something like this...

```html
<div>
  <h4>first</h4>
  <h4>second</h4>
  <h4>third</h4>
</div>
```

How to make them in same line, and the first to be on the left side, the second, on the center and the third on the right side?

Comment: If it is of any help...consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT / completely new answer (I hadn't noticed the left/center/right):

Use flexbox with `justify-items: space-between;`

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>first</h4>
  <h4>second</h4>
  <h4>third</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly your looking for
check this snippet

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>first</h4>
  <h4>second</h4>
  <h4>third</h4>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

### You're looking for the `float` property

You can read up on its specs [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float) or get an idea of its uses in [this fairly comprehensive article ("All about floats" on css-tricks.com)](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

Basically, the property tells the browser that the elements should be laid out starting from the direction specified while taking up as little space as possible. *(Actually it's quite a bit more complex than that, but anything beyond basic usage is outside the scope of this question I think)*

Combine that with setting the width to one third of the containers and centering the text on the headings and you've got what you need.

#### The CSS

```css
h4 {
  float:left;
  width: 33.3%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>first</h4>
  <h4>second</h4>
  <h4>third</h4>
</div>
```

#### Addendum

As others noted already, [flexbox (MDN link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) is also a good alternative but has a lot more quirks and support is more sporadic than for floats. Also, mastering floats is a good idea before jumping on the flexbox wagon.